# Why Separate function's returned value mutates props values in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am following a course, sorting logic comes from "sortQuotes" function and storing its returned data to "sortedQuotes" constant, so how is it possible that even though I am not passing that modified data to JSX and still rendering original props.quotes - code works and pressing sorting button changes list to ascending/descending correctly?

```
const sortQuotes = (quotes, ascending) => {
  return quotes.sort((quoteA, quoteB) => {
    if (ascending) {
      return quoteA.id > quoteB.id ? 1 : -1;
    } else {
      return quoteA.id < quoteB.id ? 1 : -1;
    }
  });
};

// props.quotes -----> [{id:'q1'},{id:'q2'},{id:'q3'}]

const QuoteList = props => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  const isSortingAscending = queryParams.get('sort') === 'asc';

  console.log(props.quotes);
// Even before "sortQuotes" function call on the first render, props.quotes are still changed in order

  const sortedQuotes = sortQuotes(props.quotes, isSortingAscending);

  const changeSortingHander = () => {
    navigate(`/quotes?sort=${!isSortingAscending ? 'asc' : 'des'}`);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className={classes.sorting}>
        <button onClick={changeSortingHander}>
          Sort {isSortingAscending ? 'Descending' : 'Ascending'}
        </button>
      </div>
      <ul className={classes.list}>
        {props.quotes.map(quote => (
          <QuoteItem
            key={quote.id}
            id={quote.id}
            author={quote.author}
            text={quote.text}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Because `sort` sorts the array [in-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm).

Comment: Ah that means the sort method mutates an original array, I should have copied the array first and then sort it,  thank you very much.